# Printing text in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have read the various ways to print separate lines in Shiny using HTML but was not satisfied. My goal is to bin various independent variables and provide the code as an SQL statement that the user can then use to bin in SAS. The text that I would eventually like to see printed in my shiny app is the result from executing the code below:

```
binbreaks <- c(17,41,65,89,113)
x_var <- "IAG01"

for (i in 1:length(binbreaks)) {
 if (i==1) {
   cat(paste("select ",x_var, ", case", "\nwhen ", x_var," <= ", binbreaks[1], "then 1"))
 }
 if (i>1 & i<=(length(binbreaks)-1)) {
   cat(paste("\nwhen ",binbreaks[i-1], " < ", x_var, " <= ", binbreaks[i], "then ", i))
 }
 if (i==length(binbreaks)) {
   cat(paste("\nelse ", i))
   cat(paste("\nend as ", x_var, "_bin"))
 }
```

The resulting text in my shiny app should be:

```
select  IAG01 , case 
when  IAG01  <=  17 then 1
when  17  <  IAG01  <=  41 then  2
when  41  <  IAG01  <=  65 then  3
when  65  <  IAG01  <=  89 then  4
else  5
end as  IAG01 _bin
```

server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$SQL_pp <- renderPrint({
    binbreaks<-seq(min(input_data_NA[[input$x_var]]),max(input_data_NA[[input$x_var]]),length.out=input$bins)
    cat(
      for (i in 1:length(binbreaks)) {
        if (i==1) {
          cat(paste("select ",input$x_var, ", case", "\nwhen ", input$x_var," <= ", binbreaks[1], "then 1"))
        }
        if (i>1 & i<=(length(binbreaks)-1)) {
          cat(paste("\nwhen ",binbreaks[i-1], " < ", input$x_var, " <= ", binbreaks[i], "then ", i))
        }
        if (i==length(binbreaks)) {
          cat(paste("\nelse ", i))
          cat(paste("\nend as ", input$x_var, "_bin"))
        }
      }
    )
  })
```

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage("EDA Tool",
    tabPanel("SQL code", textOutput("SQL_pp"))
  )
)
```

The issue is that I would like to print like the output above. Instead, my output looks all jumbled. It will still execute but I would like it to look presentable (i.e. not like this:

```
select IAG01 , case when IAG01 <= 17 then 1 when 17 < IAG01 <= 41 then 2 when 41 < IAG01 <= 65 then 3 when 65 < IAG01 <= 89 then 4 else 5 end as IAG01 _bin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML ignores linebreaks by default; you can use a `pre` element to preserve linebreaks and spacing. Replace this:

```
textOutput("SQL_pp")
```

With this:

```
textOutput("SQL_pp", container = pre)
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I wanted. Thank you SO much! In the future, if I wanted to find out about options like "container" and such, how would I go about doing that? For instance, container=pre was not listed anywhere when I was searching the textOutput documentation.